# jQuery multiple radio buttons and load html code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-animate, jquery-effects

You think is right this way for show HTML code in each click on radio?
What is you propose to animate  (effect) appropriate for show and hide html code?
see you example of my codes: http://jsfiddle.net/9LECb/

```
$('#housing_select input').click(function(){
        var classes =  $(this).attr('id');
        if(classes == 'hotel_select'){
            $('.hotel_apartment_select, .suite_select').hide();
            $('.'+classes).show();
        }
        if(classes == 'hotel_apartment_select'){
            $('.hotel_select, .suite_select').hide();
            $('.'+classes).show();
        }
        if(classes == 'suite_select'){
            $('.hotel_select, .hotel_apartment_select').hide();
            $('.'+classes).show();
        }
    })
```

With respect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can remove the if conditions and minimize the code to:

```
$('#housing_select input').click(function() {
    var classes = $("." + this.id);

    $('.hotel_apartment_select, .suite_select, .hotel_select').not(classes).hide();
    classes.show();
})
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/9LECb/2/
**Note:**
You can check [jQuery UI Tabs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/tabs/) as they acheive a similar effect

Comment: @Sheikhasa: Did not save the jsfiddle. Updated the answer. Check it

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$('#housing_select input').click(function() {
    $('.hotel_apartment_select, .suite_select, .hotel_select').not("." + this.id).hide();
    $("." + this.id).show();
})
```